# MySQL sort by name

Tags: mysql, sorting, alphabetical, alphabetized

Is ir possible to sort a column alphabetically but ignoring certain words like e.g 'The'

e.g.

A normal query would return

```
string 1
string 3
string 4
the string 2
```

I would like to return

```
string 1
the string 2
string 3
string 4
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT**
Please note I am looking to replace multiple words like The, A, etc... Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT id, text FROM table ORDER BY TRIM(REPLACE(LOWER(text), 'the ', ''))
```

but note that it will be very slow for large datasets as it has to recompute the new string for *every* row.

IMO you're better off with a separate column with an index on it.

For multiple stopwords just keep nesting `REPLACE` calls. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible to use expressions with the ORDER-part:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY REPLACE(yourField, "the ", "")
```

Comment: Might want to add a trailing space, otherwise this might cause some problems with words containing "the", eg. feather

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all leading "The " as an example

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable 
ORDER BY REPLACE(Val,'The ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a music listing that is well over 75,000 records and I had encountered a similar situation.  I wrote a PHP script that checked for all string that began with 'A ', 'An ' or 'The ' and truncated that part off the string.  I also converted all uppercase letters to lowercase and stored that string in a new column.  After setting an index on that column, I was done.

Obviously you display the initial column but sort by the newly-created indexed column.  I get results in a second or so now.